# Install Matrox MGA g200e drivers on Linux Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, drivers

I was trying to install the **Matrox MGA driver** (driver on this [page](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/support/drivers/latest/)) on my **Ubuntu 14.04** but the installation process ask me for my **X11R6 path**. I have **Xorg installed** on my computer but I can't locate the path i need. I fond on internet that commonly the folder is in /etc/X11 or in /usr/etc but it is not there, probably the folder have a new position in ubuntu 14.04
Can you hel me to locate it or suggest me an installation guide for my Ubuntu version?!

Comment: You probably have not installed the required [`libx11*-dev` package(s)](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libx11+-dev&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all).

Comment: x11 look installed I just made
sudo apt-get install xauth
sudo apt-get install xorg
sudo apt-get install openbox
and they are installed and up to date

Comment: Syntax your comment not.  The name start with `lib` and with `-dev` it ends.  Attention your paid.

Comment: I am sorry for it, just I dint't noticed that I can not start a new line in comments, I am adding punctuation ->

x11 look installed. 

I just made: sudo apt-get install xauth, sudo apt-get install xorg, sudo apt-get install openbox.

 they are installed and up to date

Comment: So you still have not tried libx11*-dev.

Comment: Finally I got back to linux 12.04, as I mentioned down, ubuntu 14.04 have some problem with the Matrox MGA so I preferred to avoid any problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question, the Matrox MGA drivers are **unclaimed in Ubuntu 14.04** because of an update of the Xorg.
I solved simply installing **Ubuntu 12.04** but it seems that the problem can also be solved overriding the new Xorg files with the old Xorg version.
You can find all the information about the argument in **[this forum](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1316035)**